# issue with Openslide package locating on Mac

Tags: macos, image-processing, openslide

Been trying to download PathmL on Mac , and i followed the documentation instructions (https://github.com/Dana-Farber-AIOS/pathml#installation).    including downloading OpenSlide, however I keep on. receiving this error, ''Couldn't locate OpenSlide dylib''

Any advice ?

All as per doucmentation instructions. I am expecting it to launch in jupyter lab

Answer (score 0):

All good, I fixed the error by doing this.

was to use conda command from a Docker terminal using this command,  <<conda install -c conda-forge openslide>> followed by Pip install openslide-python. Thank you for everything :) :) :)